# Why does TypeScript's type checker think a generic object's property can't be a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here's a minimal example:

```
function Test<T>(obj: T) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        let prop = obj[key];
        if (typeof prop === 'function') {
            prop();
        }
    }
}
```

TypeScript won't compile this, saying that `prop` inside the `if` block is of type "never".

```
Error TS2349 (TS) Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'never' has no compatible call signatures.
```

But in JavaScript, functions can and often are keyed properties of objects. So what is the problem here?

Comment: What version of TS? this seems to wrok: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAFQKYGcoB5kD4AUcARgFYBcKAlIgN4BQijiwcATovgDapSIDWqAJ6IYSYiWr0m0xN14AHVnHmIAvInEBtAYIC6AbgYzGMYByiD5qOGcXK1q9QHJQkWAieSjx6Xfn5KQx9EAF9vULoQoA

Comment: Edit: So, my project was version 2.8, but it looks like it just updated to 3.0 and this code now works. So it must have been a bug they fixed in 2.9 or 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible that since there are no clues about the generic type `T`, the variable `obj` is not treated as `any`? What happens if you change the line `Test<T>` to `Test<T extends any>`?

However, as shown in [the comment by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499468/why-does-typescripts-type-checker-think-a-generic-objects-property-cant-be-a#comment99588051_56499468), it seems like in the latest versions that is not an issue anymore.

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed this doesn't work in 2.8 but does work in 3.0. Incidentally, your suggestion doesn't work in 2.8 either, because "any" doesn't have a call signature either.